# How do i make an image be on top of page?

Tags: css, scroll, photos

How do i do so "topbar.jpg" is always on top and can not me moved.
And button.jpg that work, so you can scroll everything except them.

Answer (score 1):

For the image use CSS: `position:fixed; top:{some amount}px; left:{some amount}px;`. As for "And button.jpg that work, so you can scroll everything except them.", i dont know what you mean.

Comment: I mean that they are on top of the page always. So topbar stays in top if your scroll down the page.

Answer (score 0):

The 'position:fixed' solution should work properly.
Have you uploaded it so we can see the problem?